# Referring dependencies that don't yet exist in Maven

Tags: maven

I need to install a whole bunch of 3rd party jar files in my local repository, using maven-install plugin. That part is done with the following pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sap</groupId>
<artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
<version>${sap.version}</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>iterator</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <items>
                            <item>cecore</item>
                            <item>cesession</item>
                            <item>celib</item>
                        </items>
                        <pluginExecutors>
                            <pluginExecutor>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.4</version>
                                </plugin>
                                <goal>install-file</goal>
                                <configuration>
                                    <file>${bo.lib.dir}/@item@.jar</file>
                                    <groupId>${sap.group}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>@item@</artifactId>
                                    <version>${sap.version}</version>
                                    <packaging>jar</packaging>
                                </configuration>
                            </pluginExecutor>
                        </pluginExecutors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<properties>
    <bo.lib.dir>C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\java\lib</bo.lib.dir>
    <sap.group>com.sap</sap.group>
    <sap.artifact>sdk</sap.artifact>
    <sap.version>4.1</sap.version>
</properties>


<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

In a nutshell, I'm looping through these three items (cecore,celib, and cesession) to perform the actual installation.

I would like to then add these three items as dependencies, but since these won't exist before the package phase, Maven complains about that.

Ideally, I would like to instruct Maven to resolve the dependencies after the packaging, or to instruct Maven to trust that the dependencies will in fact become available.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks!

Eric

Comment: but what would you (maven) then do with these dependencies after the package phase?

Comment: I will then make that package a dependency for my main project. Basically what I am trying to do add as a single dependency a whole bunch of 3rd party jars.

Comment: do those generated dependencies have transitive dependencies as well?